# Hazelcast OFFHEAP Map Taking Up Space in Heap

Tags: java, memory, dictionary, heap-memory, hazelcast

I need Hazelcast to store a relatively large size of data (16GB x 3 nodes). I carried out a few tests within JVM heap memory and was more than satisfied with the results.

However, when I set the map to be stored in off-heap memory; I don't see any changes in memory usage. Shouldn't I see lower heap memory values when I use off-heap than in default BINARY in-memory-format? (I'm using a trial license and hazelcast-3.2-RC-ee JAR)

Here's the configuration file part:

```
<map name="data">
    <in-memory-format>OFFHEAP</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <statistics-enabled>false</statistics-enabled>
</map>
<map name="default">
    <in-memory-format>OFFHEAP</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>

</map>
```

And this is the related code :

```
    String instanceName = wrapper.getHazelcastInstance().getName();
    int port = wrapper.getHazelcastInstance().getCluster().getLocalMember().getInetSocketAddress().getPort();
    logger.info("Hazelcast instance " + instanceName + " is running at port " + port);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter number of data to insert :");
        String s = null;
        while (s == null) {
            s = System.console().readLine();
        }
        Long dataCount = null;
        try {
            dataCount = Long.valueOf(s.trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("That won't do :)");
            continue;
        }

        if (dataCount < 0) {
            break;
        }

        int dataSize = wrapper.getHazelcastInstance().getMap("data").entrySet().size();
        try {
            for (long l = dataSize; l < dataSize + dataCount; l++) {
                RoundRobinConsolidatedUtilizationData datum = createData();
                wrapper.getHazelcastInstance().getMap("data").put(l, datum);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.severe("Exception occurred : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            logger.severe("Error occurred; terminating instance : " + throwable.getMessage());
            break;
        }

        logger.info("Total data count in cluster: " + wrapper.getHazelcastInstance().getMap("data").entrySet().size());
    }
```

Finally, here's the command-line that I use when running my HazelcastWrapper class

```
java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M -Dhazelcast.elastic.memory.enabled=true -Dhazelcast.elastic.memory.total.size=500M -Dhazelcast.elastic.memory.chunk.size=12K -cp hazelcast-3.2-RC-ee.jar:hazelcast-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:sm-datacache-api-1.0.jar tr.com.kron.hazelcast.HazelcastWrapper
```

Actually, I tried various `-D` and `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` values. They all ended up the same.

I'm adding 3000 records at a time to the cluster (this last test included a solo node); when I add 4th 3000 records, the VM throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. If the map was really off-heap; I shouldn't be getting a heap space error.

Below is the jConsole capture of heap memory usage. The rises seen are the times I added 3K map data. The last fall of memory is when I get the OutOfMemoryError.
[image: Heap memory usage]

What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance, (even for just reading this long anyway :))

Comment: Is this exactly the same behavior as Binary? The current off-heap implementation stores the key and meta data on the heap. So it still occupies some space in heap. Version 3.3 will come with the second generation implementation of off-heap that stores everything, including the key, value and meta data off the heap. We actually tried  storing 200 GB data with 512 MB heap.

Comment: Also I see the calls like: getMap("data").entrySet(). entrySet() will bring all entries from all nodes into one heap. And OOME is actually inevitable here. You should just call map.size().

Comment: How fool of me. thanks fuad; that was it.